# batch script to delete log file if size is more

Tags: batch-file

Hi I am trying to create a Batch script to delete the log files in an application if the file size is more, here is my code. I am getting Syntax error after second "pushd"

```
@echo off
pushd "C:\Program Files\temp\Logs" 
for /f "skip=10 eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /o-d E*.log') do @del "%%F" 
for /f "skip=10 eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /o-d A*.log') do @del "%%F" 
popd
sleep 1
pushd "C:\Program Files\temp\modules\Logs"
set file="P*.log"
set maxbytesize = 10
 FOR /F "usebackq" %%A IN ('%file%') DO set size=%%~zA
   if %size% GTR %maxbytesize% (
        del "%%A"
)
```

Comment: note that this won't be able to work with files larger than 2GB due to the 32-bit math limit of cmd.exe

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc file size i am handling is not  more than 100MB

Comment: yeah as long as you know the limits it'll be fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy this code exactly and try please.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
pushd "C:\Program Files\temp\Logs" 
for /f "skip=10 eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /o-d E*.log') do @del "%%F" 
for /f "skip=10 eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /o-d A*.log') do @del "%%F" 
popd
sleep 1
pushd "C:\Program Files\temp\modules\Logs"
set file="P*.log"
set "maxbytesize=10"
for %%A in ("%file%") do (
   set size=%%~zA
   if !size! GTR %maxbytesize% del "%%A"
)
```

Comment: (and how about `if %%~za GTR ...`?)

Comment: @Gerhard I tried the code as it is. i am not seeing any error. But its not deleting the log file with size more than 10kb.

Comment: @spiky Edited, please copy entire code, I noticed you had a space also in set maxbytesize= 10

Comment: @GerhardBarnard: the quotes are a bad idea here: they force string comparison, where `2` is bigger than `100000`

Comment: the space after the `=` isn't really a problem here (but should be avoided), but the space *before* **is**.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard I tried the script , its deleting all the log files starting letter P Irrespective of the file size.

Comment: @spiky: note, `%%~zA` gives the size in Bytes (not kiloBytes, as you seem to assume).

Comment: @spiky yes, Stephan is correct, if you want 10kb you need to `set "maxbytesize=10000"`

Comment: @Stephan , Gerhard  and Lưu Vĩnh Phúc Thanks a lot. My script is working fine as desired. Just i changed the size from KiloBytes to Bytes as Stephan said.

Answer (score 1):

`for /f` pocesses the *content* of a file - not what you want here. Use a plain `for`:

```
for %%A in ("%file%") do set size=%%~zA
```

Comment: when i removed /f , i am getting ""usebackq" is unexpected " error

Comment: @spiky Yes, see the answer exactely as Stephan said. He has no usebackq in his answer.

Comment: @Gerhard thank you for highlighting it. But even after the above change i am getting syntax error

Comment: what syntax error? did you run [`for /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) and read the content?